# Java How to get the percentage between 2 datetimes

Tags: java, android, time, elapsedtime, localdatetime

I want get the percentage between two DateTimes so i can use a progress bar.

I have the following code i'm passing in two datetimes and doing the sum but i am getting an error.

```
private void getpercentage(String dateTimeStart, String dateTimeExpiration) {

    LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeStart.replace( " " , "T" ) );
    LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeExpiration.replace( " " , "T" ) );
    String start_date = start.toString().replace( "T", " " );
    String end_date = end.toString().replace( "T", " " );
    String p = Math.round( (end_date - start_date) * 100) + '%';
    Log.d("type", "Date parsed : " + p);

}
```

Comment: The percentage? Could you explain what this means in terms of two datetimes?

Comment: Maybe it would be simpler to convert your `LocalDateTime` objects to epoch and then do the calculations using those. Check the method `toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset zos)`. By the way, in order to calculate a percentage from that, I guess you should be dividing by something?

Comment: Convert them to integers (whatever way you like). `progress=(current-start)/(end-start)*100`

Answer (score 2):

You can’t do that correctly without taking time zone into account.

```
private void getpercentage(String dateTimeStart, String dateTimeExpiration) {
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();

    ZonedDateTime start = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeStart.replace( " " , "T" ) )
            .atZone(zone);
    ZonedDateTime end = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeExpiration.replace( " " , "T" ) )
            .atZone(zone);

    long total = ChronoUnit.MICROS.between(start, end);
    long passed = ChronoUnit.MICROS.between(start, ZonedDateTime.now(zone));

    long percentage = passed * 100 / total;

    System.out.println(String.valueOf(percentage) + " %");
}
```

To see how much of the day has passed:

```
    getpercentage("2020-05-30 00:00:00", "2020-05-31 00:00:00");
```

When run right now in my time zone, Europe/Copenhagen:

> 91 %

To illustrate my point about time zone: when instead run in Indian/Maldives time zone:

> 103 %

So in that time zone 30th May is already over and we’re 3 % into 31st May.

Using the `long` type and `ChronoUnit.MICROS` (microseconds) will work for spans of time up to 290 000 years. For a longer span, choose a coarrser unit. For more accuracy and a shorter span, use a finer unit, that is, nanoseconds.

### Java 9 and later

```
long percentage = Duration.between(start, ZonedDateTime.now(zone))
        .multipliedBy(100)
        .dividedBy(Duration.between(start, end));
```

The overloaded `Duration.dividedBy(Duration)` method was introduced in Java 9. This allows us to use the `Duration` class for the calculation so we don’t need to decide on a specific time unit.

Comment: Beautiful! Especially the section, `Java 9 and later` is something which I learnt today.